# How do you organize the project to support this requirement?

Tags: magento2

You are working on a Magento store which will be selling in two countries. Each country has its own set of payment methods.
How do you organize the project to support this requirement?

A. Create one website, two payment scopes

B. Create one website, one store view

C. Create one website, two store views

D. Create two websites, two store views

Can anyone answer this

Answer (score 2):

Considering **payment method enabling settings are set on website scope**, I would say option D. is the answer.

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: For multi website, URL will be changed